# counting exact matches inside text

Tags: mysql

I do have two tables.

1. Classifieds, containing a body text.
2. Keywords, containing keyword combinations like "silver ring"

Now I am trying to find out, how many exact matches are inside the text field for each keyword.

e.g:

```
chihuahua bilder    30
chihuahua charakter 230
```

Somehow my SQL-Statement is missing something:

```
SELECT k.keyword, count(*) AS c 
FROM `classifieds` c, keywords k 
WHERE c.text LIKE concat('%', + k.keyword + '%') 
GROUP BY keyword
```

The count value is always the same for each keyword.

Does somebody have an idea where the error is? Thank you for any help.

Comment: COUNT() count rows not matches. If you want to count exact matches then you will use some tricks like replacing your keyword in the haystack column with an empty string, measure the difference in length and divide by the length of the keyword. Probably you're better off with counting in the API.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing PHP and SQL, `concat('%', + k.keyword + '%')` should be `concat('%', k.keyword, '%')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is tricky sql:

```
SELECT text, keyword,
  (LENGTH(c.text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(c.text, k.keyword, ''))) / LENGTH(k.keyword)
FROM classified c INNER JOIN keywords k
   ON c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', k.keyword, '%');
```

- Let $replace = `REPLACE(c.text, k.keyword, '')`

  - This remove `keyword` from `text`
- Let $len = `LENGTH(c.text) - LENGTH($replace)`

  - This calculates "how many characters are removed from `text`"
- `$len / LENGTH(k.keyword)`

  - Finally we get how many `keyword`s `text` has.